# numpy.polyfit data export into Python pandas.core.frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am able to develop a code with the help of experts from StackOverflow. However, I got stuck in adding new attributes from 'numpy.polyfit' function and export the data to a data frame.

My Requirements:

1.Add Intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr in addition to slope (from ployfit function)

2. Import the data into core data frame.

Sample Code:

```
year = [1993, 1994, 1995, 1993, 1994, 1995] 
category =['rev', 'rev', 'exp', 'exp', 'net', 'net'] 
values = [200, 250, 42, 32, 9, 4] 
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'category': category,'values': values})

        cats = df1.category.unique().tolist()
        slopes = [np.polyfit(df1.loc[df1.category == cat, "year"], df1.loc[df1.category == cat, "values"], 1)[0] for cat in cats]
        for cat, slope in zip(cats, slopes):
            print("{} slope/trend: {:.3f}".format(cat, slope))
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you considered using the scipy.stats.linregress function?

Comment: I haven't tried. But I am open to using any.